# Outlook Add-In: The UI is different for web and Windows Desktop app

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-2010, outlook-2007

I have created an add-in using Angular 8 which works fine in web browser, but on the desktop app. I am facing two issues:

1. There are some UI inconsistencies.

[Here is a radio button on the web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8DVZ.png)

[Here is the same button on the desktop app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNLKc.png)

In HTML it is a span text. The number is dynamically updated through a variable.

2. The UI-less add-in stops working intermittently on the desktop app. I checked the logs and found this:

   ```
   23-12-2020 12:58:45     Monitorable     Manifest        Skipped unrecognized XML element for add-in ID : f7bad2f3-c4ca-492d-93cd-7828d5bd458f, Location : Element Namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" : Element Name "Tooltip", Line=70, CharPosition=20


   23-12-2020 12:58:45     Monitorable     Manifest        Skipped unrecognized XML element for add-in ID : f7bad2f3-c4ca-492d-93cd-7828d5bd458f, Location : Element Namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" : Element Name "Tooltip", Line=183, CharPosition=22
   ```

The manifest in the project is validated through Yeoman tool, so I am confused why this is occurring.

Comment: As a platform, we simply route a request to load the HTML page defined in the manifest and don't control the UI elements within it, the control beyond this completely lies with the addin. Also, depending on the client and OS versions, the taskpane uses IE/Edge to render the addin. Could you try if you're able to reproduce this behavior in both browsers?

Comment: For the second issue, could you elaborate on "The UI-less stops working intermittently"? Does it not do what's expected or is the function in the js never called or is it that the UI-less function gets called but never completes the task assigned? Please share your outlook build number and OS build numbers as well

Comment: I have tested on Internet explorer 11 (V 11.508.19041.0), Edge (Version 87.0.664.66) and Chrome (Version 87.0.4280.88). The UI is consistent in these three browsers. The only change is when its loaded in the desktop outlook.

Comment: Sometimes the add-in gives an error that it is unable to reach the add-in, without executing the task. We have checked the connectivity of the url defined in "functionFile" of the manifest and it is always available.

Comment: Could you share your outlook and windows build numbers. Also, does this error ever show up for the taskpane button of the add-in? I assume the domain of the taskpane HTML/JS is the same as the domain for the function file? One thing to try would be to use fiddler to see whether the routing to the HTML page where functionfile is defined was successful when this error happens.

Comment: Hi, The windows i have is Windows 10 Home Single Language (19041.508) and the outlook build is (16.0.13426.20352). No, it does not show up for the taskpane button. The domain is correct and the same one as the taskpane. I can share the link to the manifest over 1-1 communication for further looking into this issue. Also, these issues only occur over the desktop app. On mac and web, it works fine.

Comment: Any updates? There has been no response on this for over 2 weeks.

Comment: From your build numbers, you should be on Edge. I installed your add-in, and tried it out, and did NOT repro the issue, but my number looked like: 4 112 126 573. (with the spaces). Based on your screenshots, I would GUESS that Edge is detecting your number as a phone number, and highlighting it. Doing a google search, reveals that this has been a problem before, and there are way to deal with it? Try and adding some random digits to the end of your number to see if it stops highlighting. (to try and confirm if this is the issue).

Comment: Also what happens if you click on the link? Does it have an A HREF link? (or does it launch a phone app?)  I will try to follow up on our end, to see if we do anything special here, but it is likely that this is some feature of Edge that we don't control.

Comment: https://www.solmediaco.com/blog/how-to-remove-the-annoying-blue-links-for-numbers-automatically-created-on-edge

Comment: This worked. The solution is to add this meta tag as per the above link in the head section.

 <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following meta tag

meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"

to the head section worked for me. A more detailed answer can be found here:
https://www.howtosolutions.net/2016/10/microsoft-edge-disabling-phone-number-detection-problem/